# How to Get one Single statement of two table value in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I wanted to retrieve two table values in one single statement such as,
(Example Bank statements..)

Table 1: Invoice

```
SELECT ClientNo, InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo, TotalDue 
FROM Invoice_TBL 
WHERE ClientNo = 1 
ORDER BY InvoiceDate ASC
```

[image]

Table 2: Payment

```
SELECT ClientNo, PaymentDate, TotalAmountPaid 
FROM Payment_TBL 
WHERE ClientNo = 1 
ORDER BY PaymentDate ASC
```

[image]

The Question is how can i merge two table values and retrieve data from client wise date ascending order

I want the result like bellow screenshot

[image]

i'm new to SQL database. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly the wanted output but pretty close:

Query for versions 2012+:

```
; WITH invoices_payments AS
  ( SELECT StatementDate = InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo, TotalDue, TotalPaid = 0.0,
           ID = InvoiceID, Type = 0
    FROM Invoice_TBL 
    WHERE ClientNo = 1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PaymentDate, '', 0.0, TotalAmountPaid, 
           ID = PaymentID, Type = 1
    FROM Payment_TBL 
    WHERE ClientNo = 1 
  )
SELECT StatementDate, InvoiceNo, TotalDue, TotalPaid,
       TotalBalance = SUM(TotalDue - TotalPaid) 
                        OVER (ORDER BY StatementDate, Type, ID
                              ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM invoices_payments
ORDER BY StatementDate, Type, ID ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d254/9). I've assumed that you have a primary key (used `InvoiceID` and `PaymentID`) in the tables and I used it to make the ordering 100% determinate (so where you have more than one invoices or payments in the same day, you always get the same order in the results.)

---

For versions before 2012, there are various ways, none as efficient as the `OVER (ORDER BY ... ROWS ...)` of 2012. You can check this blog post by Aaron Bertrand about various approaches: 
**[Best approaches for running totals – updated for SQL Server 2012](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)**. The more efficient (for 2008R2 versions and older) are - as the blog post tests show - the **cursor** and the **CLR** approaches.

Following is one way using a self-join:

```
; WITH invoices_payments AS
  ( SELECT StatementDate = InvoiceDate, InvoiceNo, TotalDue, TotalPaid = 0.0,
           ID = InvoiceID, Type = 0
    FROM Invoice_TBL 
    WHERE ClientNo = 1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PaymentDate, '', 0.0, TotalAmountPaid, 
           ID = PaymentID, Type = 1
    FROM Payment_TBL 
    WHERE ClientNo = 1 
  )
SELECT a.StatementDate, a.InvoiceNo, a.TotalDue, a.TotalPaid,
       TotalBalance = SUM(b.TotalDue - b.TotalPaid) 
FROM invoices_payments AS a
  JOIN invoices_payments AS b
    ON b.StatementDate < a.StatementDate
    OR b.StatementDate = a.StatementDate AND b.Type < a.Type
    OR b.StatementDate = a.StatementDate AND b.Type = a.Type AND b.ID <= a.ID
GROUP BY a.StatementDate, a.Type, a.ID, a.InvoiceNo, a.TotalDue, a.TotalPaid
ORDER BY a.StatementDate, a.Type, a.ID ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. i also tested at  SQLfiddle working fine but when i applied in sql server management studio and execute... i'm getting error..  "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'order'. "
please help me.. Thaks again ypercube

Comment: I suppose you have different columns as PKs in your tables? Change the `InvoiceID` and `PaymentID` in my code to match your PKs (assuming you have integer columns as PKs)

Comment: Oh sorry, you have 2008R2 version. I think the aggregates with `over` were added in 2012.

Comment: yes problem in over what shall i do for that.. thanks for your answer and comments...

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer... i have a small doubt.. Why did you use Type = 0 in Invoice table and Type = 1 in Payment table

Comment: So, if you have one or more invoices and one or more payments in same day, all the invoices are ordered in the result first and the payments after.

Comment: I Have a another doubt  in Query i have asked a question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102095/how-to-merge-same-values-in-a-column-and-rows Can you please help me