# How to merge same values in a column and rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can i merge same Stock item value and get the sum of both value in the table

This is Query:

```
select Invoice_TBL.InvoiceNo
    ,Invoice_TBL.ClientNo
    ,Invoice_TBL.ClientFullName
    ,InvoiceItems_TBL.StockID
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemCode
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemCategory
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemDescription
    ,Stock_TBL.Unit
    ,Stock_TBL.NoOfUnitsInACarton
    ,SUM(InvoiceItems_TBL.Quantity) as TotalQuantity
    ,InvoiceItems_TBL.SellingPrice
    ,SUM(InvoiceItems_TBL.TotalAmount) as TotalAmount
from Stock_TBL
inner join InvoiceItems_TBL on Stock_TBL.StockID = InvoiceItems_TBL.StockID
inner join Invoice_TBL on InvoiceItems_TBL.InvoiceNo = Invoice_TBL.InvoiceNo
where (Invoice_TBL.IsTableStatus = 1)
    and (InvoiceItems_TBL.IsTableStatus = 1)
    and (Stock_TBL.IsTableStatus = 1)
    and Invoice_TBL.ClientNo = 5 --AND (Invoice_TBL.ClientNo > 0)
group by Invoice_TBL.InvoiceNo
    ,Invoice_TBL.ClientNo
    ,Invoice_TBL.ClientFullName
    ,InvoiceItems_TBL.StockID
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemCode
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemCategory
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemDescription
    ,Stock_TBL.Unit
    ,Stock_TBL.NoOfUnitsInACarton
    ,InvoiceItems_TBL.SellingPrice
order by Invoice_TBL.ClientNo asc
```

The result is

[image]

But i need to display like this (Middle Table):

[image]

from the bottom table 402 Invoice No Merge with 335 Invoice No... i don't need to display Invoice No column and stock id column... but Same Item values should be merge and Added (Total Quantity and Total amount).. i wanted, one client in each stock item how many took (total quantity and amount should be calculated) in his/her all invoices

Please Help me... Thank you

Comment: The only things I see separating the two totals is the InvoiceNo and the SellingPrice. If you leave out those columns you will get your sum. Is that acceptable for your output?

Comment: Thanks for your answer... can you do it and show in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removal as suggested in comments above. Will this work for you?

```
select 
    Invoice_TBL.ClientFullName
    ,InvoiceItems_TBL.StockID
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemCode
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemCategory
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemDescription
    ,Stock_TBL.Unit
    ,Stock_TBL.NoOfUnitsInACarton
    ,SUM(InvoiceItems_TBL.Quantity) as TotalQuantity
    ,SUM(InvoiceItems_TBL.TotalAmount) as TotalAmount
from Stock_TBL
inner join InvoiceItems_TBL on Stock_TBL.StockID = InvoiceItems_TBL.StockID
inner join Invoice_TBL on InvoiceItems_TBL.InvoiceNo = Invoice_TBL.InvoiceNo
where (Invoice_TBL.IsTableStatus = 1)
    and (InvoiceItems_TBL.IsTableStatus = 1)
    and (Stock_TBL.IsTableStatus = 1)
    and Invoice_TBL.ClientNo = 5 --AND (Invoice_TBL.ClientNo > 0)
group by Invoice_TBL.ClientNo
    ,Invoice_TBL.ClientFullName
    ,InvoiceItems_TBL.StockID
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemCode
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemCategory
    ,Stock_TBL.ItemDescription
    ,Stock_TBL.Unit
    ,Stock_TBL.NoOfUnitsInACarton
order by Invoice_TBL.ClientNo asc
```